# Only users that created their own project can see the edit page and actually edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

Is there an easy way to allow users who created their own project able to edit their work?

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

How do I check if the `current_user` that is logged in can actually edit their stuff?

If my projects URL's are something like `localhost:3000/projects/24`, I want only the user who created this project can go into `localhost:3000/projects/24/edit` to view the page and actually edit...

---

At this time of writing, now I'm thinking this might not be he best way? Maybe I need to somehow do `localhost:3000/projects/username1/24` or something? And then if they edit, it'll be `localhost:3000/projects/username1/24/edit`.... How can I accomplish this?

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
  resources :projects
end
```

My controller is just basic stuff from scaffolding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe I need to somehow do localhost:3000/projects/username1/24 or
>   something? And then if they edit, it'll be
>   `localhost:3000/projects/username1/24/edit`.... How can I accomplish
>   this?

Since user has many projects, you would probably want the url of the type:

```
localhost:3000/users/1/projects/2/edit
```

To accomplish this you would need the following setup:

```
#routes.rb

resources :users, shallow: true do # notice shallow, it will eliminate users/ from the path, but as I'm not mistaken /user_id/ as well..
  resources :projects
end
```

The controller projects should be put under:

```
app/controllers/users/projects_controller.rb
```

and it should look like

```
class Users
  class Projects
    #...
  end
end
```

With this setup you'll ensure, that user only see his projects.

```
def index
  @projects = Projects.all # user can see all projects
  #...
end

def show
  @project = Projects.find(params[:project_id])
  #...
end

def edit
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id]) # can edit only those, which he associated with
  # ...
end
```

And just make sure you are making the link_to edit visible only for the user who can edit.

As to paths:

there are two options:

```
resources :users, path: '' do # will hide the users part from path
  #...
end
resources :users, shallow: true do # will actually also hide the users/user_id part
  #...
end
```

Comment: So I changed the routes per your suggestion, however, I'm getting this: `user_projects GET    /users/:user_id/projects(.:format)          projects#index` I want to be able to eliminate, the `/users/` and just have `/:user_id/projects` (I'm sure this :user_id can be changed to the username? But also, I want everyone to be able to view the projects, and only the user who created certain projects edit them.

Comment: I was able to implement @WesFoster answer below to get the user authenticating about editing and updating, but just wanted to redo the URL issue

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the project_controller should be under user? So I should create a user folder and just put this controller under that? Isn't there an easier way? I'm thinking like maybe `get ':username/:project_id' => 'project#show'` or something? I tried to do nested routes, but there are a few broken errors, so Im thinking of other possibilities? Or is this the best way to do it?

Comment: @hellomello actually nesting controllers under corresponding folders and then creating nested routes with automatically generated routes (not manually set) is what RESTful resources are about :)

Answer (score 2):

In your projects controller, add devise's authentication:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update]
```

This will ensure that the user is logged in when trying to view the edit page.

Next, you want to ensure that the logged-in user is the owner of the project.

To do this, you'll need to modify the `edit` and `update` methods to find the `project` by more than just the params:

```
def edit
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
  #...
end

def update
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
  #...
end
```

Now, only the `current_user` who owns the project can view the edit page and send the updates.

---

**Bonus points:** If you want to refactor the code above and not use the same "@project = " line twice, you can create another `before_action` which will assign the @project for both `edit` and `update`:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!,   only: [:edit, :update]
before_action :find_project_by_user, only: [:edit, :update]

private

  def find_project_by_user
    @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Doing this, you won't have to add the same "@project = " line into both the `edit` and `update` methods.

Comment: `current_user.projects.find(params[:id])`

Comment: This method helped me authenticate. Is there any way to do with the URL issue?

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is to move beyond authentication, into authorization.  Authentication validates that the user is who they say they are.  Authorization validates that a user is allowed to perform a specific action on a specific object.  Check out the [Pundit Gem.](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).  Its really simple and easy to use.

Comment: why downvote? pundit is a good recommendation with regards to defining who can do what. +1